# System vs Game time settings?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Animal Crossing is a real time game in which things are very much progressed in 'one day at a time' measurements. The game will read your system time but it also has its own time. Is there any difference between changing the in-game time vs the system time to help go through the initial days? I am finding it common practice in this game to set your initial time back a bit to get through the tutorial sections faster so you can get into the game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See my answer to [Am I punished for playing with the game clock?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/119994/11920); basically changing the game clock repeatedly is a very bad idea.

The game clock is basically an offset of your 3DS's system time. I would recommend leaving the game clock perfectly in sync with the system clock and altering the system clock if necessary, so you always know exactly what time it is in your Animal Crossing game by looking at/setting your 3DS clock.

Comment: I once had my entire system reset on the DS (including the time) due to a battery failure. When I went back to my town (in the old Animal Crossing game) everything was overgrown with weeds. DO NOT change your system time.

Comment: @Cabbit Er, same thing happens if that time just naturally passes. Are you sure you didn't set the date improperly/the town wasn't already neglected? WW Simply had that problem that if you left for a long period time every tile would be a weed. I've screwed with time on both WW and NL, advancing a few days does no such thing.

Comment: @ Ben Brocka, When the battery failure occurred, the time got set to the default in system settings (backwards in time). I am 100% positive it was not due to neglect. It went from no weeds to all weeds. Now, I'm not 100% positive that changing the system time on the 3DS would cause such catastrophic issues, but let's just say that Mr. Resetti has taught me to just not take the chance. Animal Crossing is a game that you should play at a pace. I'd just play as it was intended and caution against taking chances, or not, I'm not a cop.